# I don't see why the variables are hidden in that order using dynamic scooping

Tags: dynamic, scope, dynamic-scope

Using (Dynamic scoping)

```
procedure Main is
     X, Y, Z : Integer;
     procedure Suba is
        A, Y, X : Integer;
        begin
          -- Suba body
        end;
     procedure Subb is
        A, B, Z : Integer;
        begin
        -- Subb body
        end;
     procedure Subc
        A, X, W : Integer;
        begin
        --- Subc body
        end;
        begin
        --- Main body
        end;
```

The question is:
For the calling sequence, state which variables are visible
during the execution of the last procedure
Main calls Suba; Suba calls Subb; Subb calls Subc

Why is the answer:
Suba: A, X, W
Subb: B, Z
Subc: Y

I tried working through it and I just don't see how that is the answer
can anyone provide an explanation

Comment: Are you sure you have the calling sequence in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call "inherits" the variables visible by its caller, and introduces its own variables. If a call introduces a variable with the same name  as one in the caller, the caller's variable is shadowed. Picture the layers like this, as visible from inside `Subc`:

```
Main                       X   Y   Z
Suba         A                 Y   Z
Subb         A   B                 Z
Subc         A          W  X
```

The variables you can see are the first ones in each column looking up from the bottom. This would suggest that from inside the call to `Subc`, you can see the following:

```
* `A`, `W`, and `X` as defined by `Subc`.
* `B` and `Z` as defined by `Subb`.
* `Y` as defined by `Suba`.
```

This reverses the rolls of `Suba` and `Subc` as you mention in the question. That answer doesn't really make sense, because `Suba` doesn't define `W` at all.

Comment: Thank you! using this I got the other questions correct so I guess it must have been a mistake in the mark scheme